# How to replace 3 strings in post title?

Tags: php, wordpress, string, replace, title

I have this code:

`<?php $wptitle = get_the_title( get_the_ID() ); $wptitle = str_replace(" – word1 word2", "", $wptitle); echo $wptitle; ?>`

But it does now work. When I put only one sting it works perfectly. I'm working in WordPress

Comment: Please could you amend your question to include the the initial contents of `$wptitle`  ( the result of calling ( `get_the_title( get_the_ID() )` ) , the expected result and the actual result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening php tag declares that the following code should be interpreted as PHP by the server (rather than just HTML and being passed onto the client)

```php
 <?php
```

The following line declares a variable with the identifier (name) `$wptitle` and sets its value equal to the result of calling the function `get_the_title` with the argument `get_the_ID`. these functions must be declared elsewhere.

```
$wptitle = get_the_title( get_the_ID() );
```

The next one reassigns the variable `$wptitle`  to be  the same string with the string "foo"  being replaced by the string "bar"

```
 $wptitle = str_replace("foo", "bar", $wptitle);
```

If you want to replace some more strings then you can repeat this line

```
$wptitle = str_replace("baz", "blink", $wptitle);
```

In such case all occurrences of the string "foo" and "bar" will be replaced.

Alternatively you can pass arrays to `str_replace` to perform multiple replacements in one go.

```
$wptitle = str_replace(array("foo", "bar", "baz"), "", $wptitle);
```

The next line prints out the contents of the variable `$wptitle`

```
 echo $wptitle;
```

Finally this line instructs the PHP interpreter that the PHP block is over

```
?>
```

For more information on the semantics of `str_replace` have a look at the [php manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

It almost works, but it does not replace hyphen "-"

```
<?php $wptitle = get_the_title( get_the_ID() ); $wptitle = str_replace(array("Word1", "Word2", "-"), "", $wptitle); echo $wptitle; ?>
```

What I mean is Word1 and Word2 is replaced but third sting which is "-" is not replaced and I dont know why...

Comment: I think the issue is arising as the character  '-' is a different character to '–', the first is  a unicode MINUS SIGN and the second slightly longer one is a  unicode EN DASH, Although they look very similar to humans, they are considered by the computer to be completely different.  In your original question it looks like you are trying to remove the EN DASH but in this answer you are removing all occurences of the Minus sign

Comment: Hi again. I tried both and it does not work. Look - `$wptitle = str_replace(array("Word1", "Word2", "-", "–"), "", $wptitle);`